# How to check if a string is in ANY ArrayList

Tags: java

So I want to check if my string is in any arraylist without having to do:
`if(ArrayList1.Contains("Test") || ArrayList2.Contains("Test") || ArrayList3.Contains("Test")) {
}`

I don't know if there is a way I could do this with a loop.

Thanks

Comment: What are your `ArrayList` variable names? Do they follow a pattern?

Comment: is Contains? or is it contains?

Comment: Yes they do, the first one is: one second one is: two third is three e.t.c up to ten.

Comment: does it contain a certain string...

Comment: How is bukkit relevant to the question? I mean you tagged it and I can't spot a connection.

Comment: I am actually using this in a plugin I am coding, checking if the player is in any of these arraylists.

Answer (score 3):

Create an ArrayList contain all your ArrayLists then loop over them, just like:

```
for(ArrayList list : arrays){//arrays contains all your arraylsits, ArrayList1, ArrayList2 ...
   return list.contains(value);
}
```

Comment: or just do .contains in an arraylist that contains all the arraylists :)

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack no, you can't

Answer (score 2):

Put the content of all ArrayLists in a Set and then query that Set.

```
Set set=new HashSet();
for (ArrayList list: allLists) {
   set.addAll(list);
}
...
return set.contains("Test");
```

Actually, ArrayList or any collection can be used instead of HashSet, but `Hashset.contains` is the fastest method.

Comment: The problem is that building the initial set is quite long. May, or may not, be faster than concatenating all lists...

Comment: Hey There, I am using HashSets, but if I want to remove the string from the hashset that I just checked, and if it did have the string in I want to remove it without having to find out which arraylist it is from

Answer (score 0):

Not many choices other than using an `if` like you do, however, if you use Guava, you can use `Iterables`:

```
if (Iterables.contains(Iterables.concat(list1, list2, etc), theString))
    // do your stuff
```

If not, create one full list containing all the others and use `.contains()` on it:

```
private static <T> List<T> concatLists(final List<T> list1, 
    final List<T>... others)
{
    final List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>(list1);
    for (final List list: others)
        ret.addAll(list);
    return ret;
}

// In code:

if (concatLists(list1, list2, etc).contains(theString))
    // do your stuff
```

Comment: Then just create a list containing all the others and use `.contains()` on it

Comment: fge make an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: I just did it with some sample code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can write custom ArrayList class, and override contains method to check unique contents.

```
public class UniqueNamesList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        String inStr = (String)o;
        for (String s : this) {
            if (inStr.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```